# about self.view.frame

Tags: objective-c, ipad, frame

I have source allowing rotate interfaceOrientation. (in viewDidLoad)

```
CGPoint point;
NSInteger itemCount;

if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
point.x = (self.view.frame.size.width - (100 * itemCount)) / 2
else
...
```

In spite of running simulator in `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` mode, I have 768 pixel of `self.view.frame.size.width` (on iPad) so I can't have appropriate value of point.x

How I can access `self.view.frame` on rotating?

Comment: Try doing the same in ViewDidAppear, instead of ViewDidLoad.

Comment: have you tried using method willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation ?

Comment: rishi // I tried on shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method.

Comment: UPT / viewDidAppear is not a solution to me. I tried it.

Comment: Does self.view have an autoresizing mask? Its width may actually be 768 even when you are in landscape if the view never resizes.